# Does the FAA have a document that details each step found in a Component Maintenance Manual?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

Is there a standard FAA document type for 'general' maintenance steps that a Component Maintenance Manual (CMM) can reference?

For example:

> Once the bulb has been locked into the socket, reference the bulb
>   cleaning section in Document XYZ for the complete bulb cleaning
>   procedure.

Where can I find Document XYZ?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question to make it a little clearer, but I might have misunderstood what you're asking. If I did, don't hesitate to edit your question again, or roll back my changes. The [tour] might also be helpful if you're new to the site.

Comment: The FAA does have the [Advisory Circular 43-xx series](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.list/parentTopicID/114), but I've never seen a CMM that references them. Most manufacturers are very risk/liability averse and won't reference anything they don't control.

Answer (score 3):

In general aviation and even working in FBOs, I have referenced AC43.13 to approve repairs that the CMM does not cover. These processes and techniques are approved by the Administrator. In general terms, the FAA tends not to tell you how to meet a requirement but rather gives the requirement then the organization has to meet that requirement through a FAA approved QMS. This process is applicable regardless if you are working with the MIDO, ACO, or FISO. In order to get down in the weeds, you would have to be very specific in your question.

Here is the link to FAA AC43.13 for everyone's review.
https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/99861

Best,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard for what they must include but not where they are to be found. The standard simply states they they be "available". According to order [8110.54A](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8110.54A.pdf) the *"document XYZ"* must be available to you and must include the following:

> **10. Component Overhaul Manual or Section.** If the aircraft, aircraft engine, or propeller maintenance information references the use of a
>   component overhaul manual, or specific section of a CMM, as the
>   appropriate location for the ICA, those applicable instructions are
>   incorporated by reference and become part of the complete set of ICA.
>   If component overhaul manual information was developed to comply with
>   14 CFR § 21.50 then the component overhaul manual, or referenced
>   section(s) are part of the ICA. **As part of the ICA, it must be
>   furnished to the owner and made available to any other person required
>   to comply with those instructions per 14 CFR § 21.50. This manual or
>   section must contain the following information:**
>
> **a.** Cleaning and
>   inspection instructions that cover the materials and apparatus to use
>   and methods and precautions to take during overhaul. These
>   instructions must include methods of overhaul inspection;
>   **b.** Details on all fits and clearances for the component relative to overhaul;
>
> **c.** Details of repair methods for worn or otherwise substandard parts with information
>   necessary to determine when to replace parts;
>
> **d.** Instructions for testing the article after overhaul. This should include test acceptance
>   criteria;
>
> **e.** Instructions for storage that identify special containers and required equipment or
>   tools. The ICA should also include the environmental restrictions for storage and storage limits;
>   and
>
> **f.** A list of tools and equipment necessary for maintenance and directions as to their
>   method of use.